# Getting UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, maven

```
private void createObject(List<Activities> listOfActivities){
  ABC object1 = new ABC();
  String value = "";
    for (Activities list : listOfActivities) {
        if (list instanceof XYZ) {
          value= ((XYZ) list).getValue();
        }
    }
    object1.setValue(value)
    listOfActivities.add(object1);
    }
 }
```

In this method I am trying to add one more object, i.e. `object1`, but I am getting a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` on the line `listOfActivities.add(object1);`.

How should I resolve this?

Comment: You can only add objects of type `Activities` or subclasses thereof to a `List<Activities>`. Unless `ABC` is a subclass of `Activities`, this is invalid.

Comment: does class `ABC` inherit from `Activities` ?

Comment: Yes, Activities is an abstract super class and it has subclasses ABC and XYZ. XYZ object is already present in that list and I am trying to add ABC object.

Comment: @Gendarme it indeed is. Sangeet, you should refer that link.